# How to avoid duplicate results while multithreading / multiprocessing in Python?

Tags: python

I started programming in Python just a couple weeks ago. I have some experience with Java, so it wasn't too hard too hard for me to set up.

Right now I have a program that uses URLLib to scrape the source code of a list of sites.

I have thousands of sites to scrape, so I'm obviously looking to make it multi-threaded or multi-processed (I don't really know the difference).

The good thing is that my multi-threading works! But it's basically pointless for me to do, because all of my threads are scraping the exact same sites and giving me nothing but duplicates.

How can I avoid this issue? Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: Without sample code, it will be difficult to help. Please provide a [minimal, complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: as a general principal, I suggest you look at the `queue` module, your threads can pull items to work on from the queue without duplicates

Comment: I didn't provide my code simply because I wanted a general answer, not just a solution to my specific problem.

Ofer, thanks for your answer. Looking into Queue fixed my problem! I see how it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between multithreading and multiprocessing is important in python because the Global Interpreter Lock prevents threads from executing code simulteaneously in the interpreter. For web scraping purposes it's fine to use threading as long as your thread only executes the web request (so that only the thread blocks while waiting). If you also want to to some processing of the responses in parallel, it's better to use `multiprocessing` so that each subprocess will have it's own interpreter and you can leverage your cpu cores.

Regarding the issue with duplicates, there is probably a bug in the way you distribute the list of sites to the threads or subprocesses. In `multiprocessing` you have a `Queue` which is process-safe (thread-safe too). This means that if two subprocesses try to `get` from the queue at the same time, they will be given sequential items from the queue, instead of the same one.

In summary, You should `put` each site in the `Queue` from the main thread and then `get` from each worker thread or subprocess.

Comment: apparently, I can reproduce his result. The queue is unsafe and with 20 processes 3 of them are mostly doing the exact same thing
the same with multiprocessing locks - they don't work, don't unlock. Shame on you, python.

Comment: multiprocessing queues are both thread and process safe. There's a bug in your code.

Comment: Seriously, I found none. I scanned the code for two hours.
I ended up rewriting the whole thing and using futures & process pools. I was also searching for a memory leak which magically vanished (maybe adding exit to a function fixed it?).
I still like Python :D